# Using tf.gather or tf.gather_nd

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, tensorflow2.0

I have an input of dimension `(BATCH_SIZE*A*B*FEATURE_LENGTH)`. Now I want to select k(out of B) rows from each of A blocks from each input sample. The k values for each of the A blocks is different.
For eg.

```
inp = ([[[[ 5, 38, 40, 13, 28],
         [12,  6, 36, 20, 23],
         [44, 35, 23, 46,  3]],

        [[22, 32, 36, 20, 42],
         [ 0, 19, 41, 36, 17],
         [ 9, 35, 44,  7, 19]],

        [[27, 10, 22, 10, 48],
         [16, 42, 27,  7, 38],
         [35, 32, 15, 39, 28]]]])
#size (1,3,3,5) = (1,A,B,FEATURE_LENGTH)
```

Now say k=2 i.e I want to extract 2 rows from each of the 3 blocks. I want

```
row 0 and 1 from 1st block
row 1 and 2 from 2nd block
row 0 and 2 from 3rd block
```

That means I want my output to look like

```
([[[[ 5, 38, 40, 13, 28],
    [12,  6, 36, 20, 23]],
   
    [[ 0, 19, 41, 36, 17],
     [ 9, 35, 44,  7, 19]],

    [[27, 10, 22, 10, 48],
     [35, 32, 15, 39, 28]]]])
#op shape = (1,3,2,5)
```

I found that using `tf.gather_nd` this is possible if we provide indices as

```
ind = array([[[[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1]], [[0, 1, 1], [0, 1, 2]], [[0, 2, 0], [0, 2, 2]]]])
```

But if I have input of size `(1,16,16,128)` and `k=4`, creating this long index sequence will get tedious.
Is there any simpler way to do it in Tensorflow-2?
Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `tf.gather()` with `batch_dims` argument:

```
inds = tf.constant([[[0, 1], [1, 2], [0, 2]]])
output = tf.gather(inp, inds, batch_dims=2)
```

Comment: Thank you! That worked..I tried using tf.gather before asking here but put ```axis=2``` instead of ```batch_dims=2``` and that was causing issue!